# python else syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

This Python script to process a string is suffering from Syntax error in line 24, `else:`.

Any ideas as to what it might be?

```
j=raw_input("Enter a string: ")
import os
def addtoClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
os.system(command)
def parse(string):
    result=""
lineList=string.split("\n")
for i in range(len(lineList)):

    h=lineList[i].split("@")
if len(h)<2:
    continue
if len(h)>2:
    count=0
for x in range(len(h)):
    if x==len(h)-1:
       continue
re0=count+len(h[x])+(x*1)
re1=i+1
re3=str(re1)+"-"+str(re0)
result+=str(re3)+", "
count+=len(h[x])
else:
re0=len(h[0])
re1=i+1
re3=str(re1)+"-"+str(re0)
result+=str(re3)+", "
result =result[:-2]
addtoClipBoard(result)
print result
parse(j)
```

Comment: That's a scary indentation in the question. Can you indent your code according to your original code?

Comment: Or, if that is the indentation of the original code, then we have found the problem.

Comment: Based on the comments in the below answers, it seems you are confused about why we mean when we are asking you for the indentation of the original code.  While usually frowned upon on Stack Overflow, please take a screenshot of the code as it appears on your screen and include a link to it here so we can see if you simply pasted the code incorrectly in your question or if the indentation really is poor.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a problem with the indentation level of the `else`, make sure to align it at the same level of the corresponding `if`. Please use a good IDE or text editor to help you catch this kind of errors. As it is, it's nearly impossible to se what you intended to do with the code.

Comment: It's likely not `else`'s indentation that's wrong, but rather some of the code before and after it.

Comment: Then, please update your question with the correct indentations.

Comment: @NayanGoenka Then please update the code in your question to match your real code.  As it is written, the problem with the code in your question *is* indentation.

Comment: @NayanGoenka the problem _is_ the indentation, that `else` in line 24 is plain wrong

Comment: can u suggest indentation?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) first

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation to define what is inside of a block of code (`for`,`if`,`elif`,`while`,`with`) You want to keep everything at the same indentation within the block and then go back a level to write your `else` statement

Also it doesn't look like your else: statement even belongs there, there is no `if` statement preceding it that would imply the need for an `else` are you sure that `else` is what you want?

Here is my suggestion without knowledge of what you want your code to do, based on observation of patterns

```
for x in range(len(h)):
  if x==len(h)-1:
    continue
  if (###My condition goes here###):
    re0=count+len(h[x])+(x*1)
    re1=i+1
    re3=str(re1)+"-"+str(re0)
    result+=str(re3)+", "
    count+=len(h[x])
  else:
    re0=len(h[0])
    re1=i+1
    re3=str(re1)+"-"+str(re0)
    result+=str(re3)+", "
  result =result[:-2]
  addtoClipBoard(result)
print result
parse(j)
```

Comment: i tried doing that too. didnt help. Can you suggest identation accordingly?

Comment: @NayanGoenka it doesnt even look like the else block belongs there, what are you trying to do?

Comment: its a script to process a string and count some characters.

Comment: @NayanGoenka Since indentation is part of the logic in Python, it's impossible to suggest "correct" indentation without knowing what you want your code to do.

Comment: @NayanGoenka what do you want the `if:` `else:` block to do?

Comment: the script is made to answer the challenge on the following link

Comment: that link requires a login @NayanGoenka, just tell us what you want the if block to do

Comment: what do you want the if block to do? @NayanGoenka

Comment: i didnt make the script. No idea.Some other contestant gave it to me. Now many people circulated it so this is the correct script. Indentation has to be rectified.

Comment: i ensure you it is not correct, there is an else statement with no if statement @NayanGoenka see my edit suggestion

Comment: @NayanGoenka : Look into what `enumerate()` and `index()` do. Hint - Giving the answer (without taking input etc) is a 2 line code.